# Oracle: extract year from date in listagg

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, listagg

I have a table with date column and would like to obtain a string with distinct years:

```
ID   DATA
1    01/01/2010
2    02/01/2010
3    01/03/2011
4    03/01/2014
5    05/02/2014
```

From the above table and using `listagg` I want to get the years

```
2010
2011
2014
```

But when I run the following query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(EXTRACT(year from data),',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data)
FROM (SELECT distinct EXTRACT(year from data) 
      FROM t_teste)
```

I get the following error

ORA-00904: "DATA": invalid identifier

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are attempting to use the column `DATA`. Is it in the table `t_teste`?

Answer (score 3):

You're using a subquery that is not specifying an alias for your extracted year value, and the `data` column from your table is no longer visible - as it is only in scope inside the subquery.

You can add a column alias and then refer to that directly in the outer query, without needing another extract:

```
select listagg(anno, ',') within group (order by anno)
from (
  select distinct extract(year from data) as anno
  from t_teste
);

LISTAGG(ANNO,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYANNO)
-----------------------------------------
2010,2011,2014
```